# Does anyone know how to get the creation time of a stream from azure-datalake-store SDK?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I just found the "lastModifiedTime" and "ExpiryTime" in the class DirectoryEntry.

Answer (score 0):

You can get or set the `DateTimeOffset` when the File was created using `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File` SDK.

`public DateTimeOffset? CreationTime { get; set; }`

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file.fileproperties.creationtime?view=azure-dotnet-legacy